# EJS - closing bracket not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a problem with the EJS compiler. I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in C:\my-path\my-project\views\shop\orders.ejs while compiling ejs

I know, it should be pretty obvisous, but I don't see what's wrong.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
<%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>

<div class="container clearfix">
    <h1>Your Orders</h1>

    <% if(orders.length <= 0) {
        %> <h2>You have no orders!</h2> <%
    } else {%>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order No</th>
                    <th>Products</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% orders.forEach(order => { 
                    let totalPrice = 0;%>
                   <tr>
                        <td><%= order.id %></td>
                        <td><%= order.products.forEach(item => { %>
                            <li>
                                <%= item.title %>(<%= item.orderItem.quantity %>)    
                            </li>
                        <% totalPrice += item.quantity * item.price; }); %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= totalPrice %>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <% } %>
</div>
<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why node js is not recognizing ending brackets for ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025818/why-node-js-is-not-recognizing-ending-brackets-for-ejs)

Comment: I already saw the question you are linking there. Maybe I'm routine-blinded, but I don't see any typo in my code.

Comment: Never mind. "<%= order.products.forEach..." should be without the "=".